# Rails 3 + CarrierWave + Rspec: model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, carrierwave

I have Photo model and i implemented file uploading via CarrierWave (my app works great):

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :description, :length => { :maximum => 500, :message => :max_length_message }
  validates :image, :presence   => { :message => :presence_message }
end
```

Now i want to check in my model spec that model with given path image would be save (i uploaded the file in a given path):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Photo do
  before(:each){ @attr = { :description => "some text is here", :image => "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/violin.jpg" } }

  describe "DB" do
    it "should create with valid params" do
      expect do
        Photo.create( @attr )
      end.should change( Photo, :count ).by( 1 )
    end
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work:

```
1) Photo DB should create with valid params
     Failure/Error: Photo.create( @attr )
     CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart:
       You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed.         
    If this is a file upload, please check that your upload form is multipart encoded.
```

What is a correct way to handle that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved it:

```
before(:each){ 
   @attr = { :description => "some text is here", 
             :image => File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/files/violin.jpg')) } 
}
```

Comment: Im using your solution and get the same error as above :( **edit, was being silly, ignore me! upvoted **